# Trying to exclude category from new Wordpress 3.8

Tags: wordpress

My, WP_Query was working fine ignoring a particular category. Now, it's no longer working.

```
$wp_query->query( array( 'post_type' =>'post', 'posts_per_page'=>15, 'cat'=> -9,'paged' => $paged ) );
```

Can someone help me please?

Comment: Well this should work, nothing is wrong in your query. You can try putting exclude rule in a new line like : $wp_query= new WP_Query( 'cat=-9' ); before execution?

Comment: It doesn't work :/ This worked before, but it just stopped working a couple hours ago when I upgraded to 3.8

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try the way as mentioned in the codex : [Exclude_Posts_From_Some_Category](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop#Exclude_Posts_From_Some_Category)

```
<?php query_posts($query_string . '&cat=-3,-8'); ?>
 <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
```

**Update**: If you are loading posts via ajax, you can consider looking at https://github.com/dcooney/wordpress-ajax-load-more . Its very easy to configure and pass your options for the wp_query like excluding a cateegory or a list of categories.

If you are looking for a plugin this is the best https://github.com/ByScripts/wordpress-ajax-posts-loader

Comment: I need the pagination since I'm running infinite scroll, and I remember using wp_query for the pagination and posts per page.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, used:

```
$wp_query->query( array( 'post_type' =>'post', 'posts_per_page'=>15, 'category__not_in'=> 9,'paged' => $paged ) );
```

and it worked...  'category__not_in'